# Interpretation of the meaning "by rain or water..."

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm confused with the meaning of the following sentence which is extracted from an insurance wording:

"*damage by water or rain other than **by water or rain entering the building through openings made in its fabric by the direct force of the storm or tempest**"*

From my point of view, the above sentence is susceptible of two different interpretations:

1. By water or rain (entering the building through openings made in its fabric) by the direct force of the storm or tempest
   => It means that water or rain here are caused by the effects of storm or tempest
2. by water or rain entering the building (through openings made in its fabric by the direct force of the storm or tempest)
   => It means that the openings are made by the effects of storm or tempest.

Can you tell me which one is correct?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the difference between 1 and 2? What is your interpretations? I understand this as "damage by water or rain other than by water or rain [entering the building through openings {made in its fabric by the direct force of the storm or tempest}]" in which those markers highlight the participle clauses.

Comment: "1. It means that water or rain here are caused by the effects of storm or tempest; 2. It means that the openings are made by the effects of storm or tempest." Here is my intent. Thanks for your comment and advice (I have edited the original post). So does it mean you prefer the option 2?

Comment: I see, I myself almost always consider that the participle or (reduced relative clause) modifies what follows it immediately. So, I think the intended meaning is 2. However, I am not a native. Let's wait for them :D

Comment: I would say 2. It doesn't state where the water is coming from. Being an exclusion, probably only a lawyer would know for sure, since it doesn't really make logical sense (storms and tempests usually have rain and flood water).

Comment: I would say meaning one, water or rain caused by the storm or tempest in that way the insurance company differentiates between that and  water damage caused by other sources of water such as a water tank in the building that is damaged during the storm, a pipe that bursts etc.